# Assembly: Get the value at a position in a lookup table

Tags: assembly, avr, lookup-tables

I'm very new to assembly language and what I need to do is find the value at a given position in a lookup table. So for example, given the table:

```
table: .db 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

How would I get the 3rd element of this table and load it into a register, say r16?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the base address of the table into register `X`, add the appropriate offset, then use `LD` to fetch the entry from data memory. If your table is in program memory, use register `Z` and the `LPM` instruction.

Comment: Thank you for the response, how do I reset the offset so that I don't keep adding offset's and get an overflow?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Just reload the base address?

Comment: that makes sense, I was just wondering if there's a special way of doing it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you know the delta from the previous element instead, you can of course keep jumping around without reloading. PS: for program memory (or if you have more than 256 bytes of data memory), make sure you use 16 bit addition.

Comment: ...say I have 2 lookup tables and I want to load from a position in one or the other... How can I select which one to use when loading program memory?

Comment: You use some conditional and load the address of the appropriate table into the register?